# While loop reads only the first match and ignores the others

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is the code skips the first echo statement no matter what.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE   index_no ='456'");

($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));

if ($row['index_no'] !== '456' && $row['lesson'] !== "Fertilisation process"  )
{
    echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">Fertilisation process</a>';
}
else
{
    echo 'Fertilisation process Completed';
}
```

Comment: There's not a while loop in your code!

Comment: Please ask a question with full detailed code that you have done actually.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    if ($row['index_no'] !== '456' && $row['lesson'] !== "Fertilisation process") { // this is redundant as  your query handles this
        echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">Fertilisation process</a>';
    } else {
        echo 'Fertilisation process Completed';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your query selects rows with index_no='456'

in your if statement:

```
$row['index_no'] !== '456'
```

will always return false since what you select from the database will always have:

```
$row['index_no'] == '456'
```

... I'm not sure what you want to do exactly but thats is the problem with your code.

also there is no loop in your code. the if statement will happen only once.

Comment: I want to see 'lesson completed' for each matching database entry, but only the first entry works, while the ones below are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You missing  loop.

Do  like this.

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))){

//if else code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Added your code, and got the echo statement three times. Fertilisation process CompletedFertilisation process CompletedFertilisation process Completed